# how to achieve RFID programming for android

Tags: android, rfid

I am not even sure whether this can be done or not!

Searched for it but couldn't find much help on the subject So here I am.
Is RFID programming for reading tags possible for Android OS? Can I have RFID enabled on my phone instead of a keycard?

Thanks in advance, any help on the subject is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFID in Android phone is achieved by NFC.

You can write & read tags of various kinds.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: Thanks but I figured this out already. Isn't there any other way to do that. NFC enabled phones are limited right now so it won't help to develop such an app.

Comment: Since it requires hardware and not only software its a problem.. Its true NFC enabled phones are not yet popular, but nowadays almost every new phone has this capability... you look the Play Store for NFC app there are quite a few...